# How to remove a list element from Room where list is store as column

Tags: android, database, android-room

I am creating a database in which I have a custom list as a column with TypeConverters. 
There is a case in which I have to remove a particular element of a list.

Can anyone help in writing a query?

Answer (score 0):

In Dao interface you can use the following.

If you Know the object which is to be deleted, then use this.

```
@Delete
void delete(News news);
```

If you want to delete more than one object where it meets certain condition, use this.

```
   @Query("DELETE FROM table WHERE title = :titleDesc")
void deleteItem(String titleDesc);
```

Comment: Will it work for the list that is present within the table ? Example : i have a user table  which have a list as column item and now i have to remove a element of list

Comment: yes, here one of the column name is title, you can put your table column name in the condition.

Comment: Eloborate little more.

Comment: For example I have a user table in which I store a custom List(A), There is a case in which I have to update/remove certain position in A (List)

Comment: Hey @AnkitaChopra did you find any solution for your question, is there any way to do this in room